# Animated movie where a forest spirit deer thing gets its head cut off and its body become a wild demon

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I vaguely remember the plot revolved around a quest to save a princess.

Comment: What's a g-d deer?

Comment: @moopet, I believe that's a Jewish construction (?) and the missing letter is "o".

Comment: G-D deer = God Damned deer?

Comment: It's a cautionary effort to avoid using his name in vain. Just in case. Used most commonly by Jews, but other people too.

Comment: @JRE, I think a deer that is some sort of god.  Or "forest spirit" as Forral put it, which is probably a better choice.

Comment: For additional details, see: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193696/anime-where-this-black-haired-boy-goes-to-rescue-this-girl-from-a-villain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found it, Princess Mononoke from 1997. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I recognised this immediately, the scene you describe is from the climax. It's a good film, glad you found it again!