# Anime where this black haired boy goes to rescue this girl from a villain

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

Around 2006 I watched an anime (movie) where this black haired boy goes to rescue this girl from a villain. I don’t remember the girl but I distinctly remember two scenes.

The first is while on his quest to find a boy he stops in a village to help some women work on some form of a press where they pushed with their feet.

The second is at the end where in the climax the boy defeats the villain which I think was a black mass/goo. He wins and there is a bright white light and then he embraces the girl.

Comment: Did the boy in this movie ride an antelope?  Did the film involve a lot of giant talking animals?  It *might* be [Princess Mononoke](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119698/), but it's been a while since I watched it and I'm not sure about the bright light at the end.

Comment: That’s it. It’s been over a decade since I’ve watched it. Thanks!

Comment: @Chick, please formally accept the answer below (using the green checkmark at top left of the answer). This will make it more obvious that the answer provided was correct. Welcome!

Answer (score 16):

This is a distorted recollection of [Hayao Miyazaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki)'s [*Princess Mononoke*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Mononoke) produced by [Studio Ghibli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_Ghibli).

[image: Prince Ashitaka]
The young man is Prince Ashitaka.

[image: Princess Mononoke]
The young woman, is San, daughter of the wolf goddess Moro, often called by the sobriquet "Princess Mononoke".

[image: Lady Eboshi]
The "[women of the forge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrTjsymc6sM)" are a group of former prostitutes who work the giant bellows in the main forge in Iron Town, which is a fortified iron-manufacturing village run by Lady Eboshi (who is a former pirate captain in backstory not appearing in the film).

The black mass/goo was not a villain, but the fatally-injured great forest spirit in one of his two forms, whom Ashitaka and San struggle to protect. This part is a bit of a simplification, as the nature of the "black goo" is learned slowly over the course of the film, beginning with its first scene.

[image: Great forest spirit forms]